# Clever ways of turning a two-input function into a variable-length-input function in matlab

Tags: function, matlab, arguments

This is just a question out of interest. Suppose I have a binary function that accepts square matrices and outputs square matrices of the same size (or more generally, it's input type and size are the same as its output type and size):

```
function C = myfunc(A,B)
```

An example would be the mtimes funcion. What are some different and clever ways of turning this into a variable length input function

```
function C = myfunc_multi(varargin)
```

such that

```
myfunc(A{1},myfunc(A{2},myfunc(A{3},...myfunc(A{end-1},A{end})...))) == 
    myfunc_multi(A{:})
```

?

This is the first general solution that has come to me (edit: besides recursion or a loop):

```
function C = multioutput(functionhandle, varargin)
    n = length(varargin);
    funcstr = functiontostring(functionhandle);
    str = regexprep(arrayfun(@num2str,1:n-1),'(.)',[funcstr '(varargin{$1},']);
    C = eval(sprintf('%svarargin{%d}%s',str,n,repmat(')',1,n-1)));
end
```

then you can test it with something like

```
A = {rand(3) rand(3) rand(3) rand(3) rand(3)};
multioutput(@mtimes,A{:})-A{1}*A{2}*A{3}*A{4}*A{5}
```

to test it. Any other ways you can think of?

Comment: Sorry, but avoiding a simple loop by complex use of arrayfun, regexprep and eval is just foolishness. Learn to write simple code when it is appropriate. A loop here is just that. This mess saves no time in the evaluation, but it will be exactly that if you ever need to debug it - a mess.

Comment: In addition I'd advise against using recursion (since you mentioned it). Waste of time and memory.

Comment: @woodchips,@yuk: As I said, this question was out of interest. As with any programming language, I enjoy seeing the neat tricks, and the roundabout or unexpected ways in which things can be done. I was thinking more along the lines of [IOCCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest) than practicality. I do write "simple code" when I am actually using Matlab for computation.

Answer (score 5):

There is probably no good reason to avoid the obvious recursive construct.  It is simple, easy to read and maintain, and should have pretty good performance.

```
function out = aggregate_inputs(fHandle, varargin)
if nargin>3
    out = fHandle(varargin{1},aggregate_inputs(fHandle,varargin{2:end}));
elseif nargin <= 3
    out = fHandle(varargin{:});
end
```

Not quite as elegant, but (perhaps*) requiring less memory is the loop construct

```
function accumulate = aggregate_inputs(fHandle,varargin)
if nargin<=3
    accumulate  = fHandle(varargin{:});
else
    accumulate = fHandle(varargin{end-1},varargin{end});
    for ix = (length(varargin)-2):-1:1
       acumulate = fHandle(varargin{ix}, accumulate);
    end
end
```

Of course, your question removed those constructs from consideration ... so there's not really a good way to do it that I can see.

---

To wax philosophical for a minute, it is true that many Matlab operations can be made much much faster by using vectorized calls.  Sometimes this is interpreted as "avoid loops at all costs".  However, avoiding loops with calls to cellfun, arrayfun, or (please no) eval, does not usually increase performance.  Sometimes it is the right thing to do for other reasons ... but it does not help "vectorize your code to make it faster".

---

*The "perhaps" above is simply because I'm not sure how well Matlab's lazy copy-on-write and other optimizations would prevent the memory usage which seems like a potential hazard with the recursive solution.

Comment: I could easily be not thinking right, but I assume you meant to write `out = fhandle(varargin{1}, aggregate_inputs(fHandle,varargin{2:end}))` as your recursive step in the first function.