# Getting the N-dimensional product of vectors

Tags: matlab, nested-loops, matrix-multiplication, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to write code to get the 'N-dimensional product' of vectors. So for example, if I have 2 vectors of length L, x & y, then the '2-dimensional product' is simply the regular vector product, R=x*y', so that each entry of R, R(i,j) is the product of the i'th element of x and the j'th element of y, aka R(i,j)=x(i)*y(j).

The problem is how to elegantly generalize this in matlab for arbitrary dimensions. This is I had 3 vectors, x,y,z, I want the 3 dimensional array, R, such that R(i,j,k)=x(i)*y(j)*z(k).

Same thing for 4 vectors, x1,x2,x3,x4: R(i1,i2,i3,i4)=x1(i1)*x2(i2)*x3(i3)*x4(i4), etc...

Also, I do NOT know the number of dimensions beforehand. The code must be able to handle an arbitrary number of input vectors, and the number of input vectors corresponds to the dimensionality of the final answer.

Is there any easy matlab trick to do this and avoid going through each element of R specifically?

Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, I see now your edit about not knowing the number of dimensions. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think by "regular vector product" you mean outer product.

In any case, you can use the `ndgrid` function. I like this more than using `bsxfun` as it's a little more straightforward.

```
% make some vectors
w = 1:10;
x = w+1;
y = x+1;
z = y+1;

vecs = {w,x,y,z};

nvecs = length(vecs);

[grids{1:nvecs}] = ndgrid(vecs{:});

R = grids{1};
for i=2:nvecs
    R = R .* grids{i};
end;

% Check results
for i=1:10
    for j=1:10
        for k=1:10
            for l=1:10
                V(i,j,k,l) = R(i,j,k,l) == w(i)*x(j)*y(k)*z(l);
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;

all(V(:))

    ans = 1
```

Comment: Hi Nigel. Thank you! I actually dont know the dimensions beforehand (just edited the question).

Comment: I edited with a more general version. As long as you have a cell array with your vectors, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in function `bsxfun` is a fast utility that should be able to help.  It is designed to perform 2 input functions on a per-element basis for two inputs with mismatching dimensions.  Singletons dimensions are expanded, and non-singleton dimensions need to match.  (It sounds confusing, but once grok'd it useful in many ways.)

As I understand your problem, you can adjust the dimension shape of each vector to define the dimension that it should be defined across.  Then use nested `bsxfun` calls to perform the multiplication.

Example code follows:

```
%Some inputs, N-by-1 vectors
x = [1; 3; 9];
y = [1; 2; 4];
z = [1; 5];

%The computation you describe, using nested BSXFUN calls
bsxfun(@times, bsxfun(@times, ...  %Nested BSX fun calls, 1 per dimension
    x, ...                         %    First argument, in dimension 1
    permute(y,2:-1:1) ) , ...      %    Second argument, permuited to dimension 2
    permute(z,3:-1:1) )            %    Third argument, permuted to dimension 3

%Result
% ans(:,:,1) =
%      1     2     4
%      3     6    12
%      9    18    36
% ans(:,:,2) =
%      5    10    20
%     15    30    60
%     45    90   180
```

To handle an arbitrary number of dimensions, this can be expanded using a recursive or loop construct.  The loop would look something like this:

```
allInputs = {[1; 3; 9], [1; 2; 4], [1; 5]};

accumulatedResult = allInputs {1};
for ix = 2:length(allInputs)
    accumulatedResult = bsxfun(@times, ...
        accumulatedResult, ...
        permute(allInputs{ix},ix:-1:1));
end
```

Comment: Thank you pursuit. This is very helpful, but still not the whole story. I don't know the number of dimensions beforehand (it is a parameter), so how can I modify this code for arbitrary N dimensions?

Comment: See edit for loop implementation.  This reminds me of a simiar (but kind of off-the-wall) question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9337114/931379